# Where should I put functions not related to any single child object but rather related to the "collection" of them?

Tags: php, function, oop, inheritance

I have recently taken on a simple php project to get to know OOP a little better.

Basically the project consists of a single table where multiple items of different types (food, furniture, electronics, etc.) can be inserted.

I have an `abstract class Items()` that constructs the connection to the database and defines an `abstract function save_item()`. I also have a class for each item type that extend Items() i.e. `class FurnitureItem extends Items()`

An `ItemsFactory()` class just generates the correct object.

This is done due to the fact that each item type has slightly different properties and the input data should be handled differently.

However, I also have functions such as `fetch_items()` (just outputs all items from the table) and `delete_items()` (bulk deletes items not caring about their type). These functions *function* irrelevant of item type.

My question is, where should I put `fetch_items()` and `delete_items()`?

Clearly, they are not relevant to a specific item type (therefore should not be defined in child classes), however defining them in the parent class `Items()` seems illogical as the child classes would inherit these functions as well. But they shouldn't, for the reason above.

Should I make a new class for just these functions? Then in essence I would be making a class that contains just the generic functions of the project.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like a good time for a helper class you include in each script utilizing those functions

Comment: It seems like those methods would fit better in the factory, or in a repository class that the factory could access.

Comment: Sounds like you might want a Collection.

Answer (score 0):

> Clearly, they are not relevant to a specific item type (therefore should not be defined in child classes), however defining them in the parent class Items() seems illogical as the child classes would inherit these functions as well. But they shouldn't, for the reason above.

But you DO want to define these functions for each of the subtypes. You want the `FurnitureItem` class to have a `delete_items()` function (because you will be calling this function for this class later). Since that function is common to other subtypes, it makes sense to include this in parent `Items` class, because that's the base implementation for deleting any 'Items'. Base classes are usually always used to contain logic common to all child classes.

Also, if you want a custom implementation of `delete_items()` later for a particular sub-class, you can override the function in that class